# how to make a button redirect to another xml page

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, button

I'm making a button in xml, like this:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttondp"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/thisisstringtext" />
```

and I want it to direct it to another page coded in xml. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: It seems you're not familiar with multiple activities. You should follow [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)

Comment: It's android basics. Go read about activities.

Comment: yeah im new to android stuff :p

Answer (score 4):

Make another activity and use

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_other_layout);
```

inside of it.

Then in the onClickListener for your button put this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, YourOtherActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the onclick listener to your button, so: `android:onclick="method_in_your_activity"`.

In your activity added the method (method_in_your_activity) and add `startActivity(NewActivity)`.

Comment: sorry for accidental downvote and comment... It supposed to go to some other question

Answer (score 0):

If you dynamically want to change the Content of your activity you can always call `setContentView(my_layout)` and change the content. However; its best practice to use another Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different activities for different layout. But if you want to use same activity for different layout then you should go for `ViewFlipper` . You can also get some animation when switching from one view to another. Tutorial regarding the same can be found [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-use-viewflipper).

Answer (score 0):

using this code in java file you will click button to redirect next page

public void onClick(View v) 
    {

```
Intent ia=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),second.class);
startActivity(ia);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your button XML, add :

```
android:onCLick="myRedirectFunction"
```

In your MyMainActivity.java, add function named myRedirectFunction and inside that function :

```
Intent homepage = new Intent(MyMainActivity.this, MySubActivity.class);
startActivity(homepage);
```